# Why private static field = new Singleton is not lazy in Java?

Tags: java, singleton

I read a lot of articles about Singleton, in most of which authors said that this variation of Singleton in Java:

```
public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    private Singleton() {}
    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

is **NOT LAZY** (*EAGER then*).

But I can't understand why, `Singleton()` constuctor will be invoked only on `Singleton` class initialization. I know several reasons, which can trigger class initialization:

1. Using `new` with constructor (but in this case constructor is private).
2. Accessing or setting up static field (here private).
3. Using static method.
4. With reflection: `Class.forName("Singleton")`.

So here our object will be created only on using static method `getInstance()` (it is still **LAZY** initialization I guess) and with reflection (but reflection can ruin a lot of Singleton variations, except `enum` maybe).

Maybe I can't see something obvious, explain me please, where was I wrong?

Comment: Your code *is* an example of lazy creation. As long as there’s no other way of *using* your class, as you have guessed yourself, it’s created lazily on demand (and using Reflection would be just another way of demanding initialization). So you’re right.

Comment: Here is my plan for world domination: 1) Prefer the `enum` Singleton pattern. 2) Realize that Singletons are a bad idea to begin with, no matter how you implement them. 3) Educate people on stackoverflow why Singletons are a bad idea. 4) Retire and drink Margaritas on the beach.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Basically it's a matter of degrees of laziness. It's lazy in that it won't construct the singleton until the class is initialized, but it's eager in that there *could* be situations where you want to use the class without initializing the singleton itself.

For example:

```
public final class Singleton {
    private static final Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    private Singleton() {}

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public static void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
}
```

Calling `Singleton.sayHello()` will instantiate the singleton even if we don't want it to... so it's not as lazy as it could be.

You can get round this using a nested type:

```
public final class Singleton {
    private Singleton() {}

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return Holder.instance;
    }

    public static void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }

    private static class Holder {
        private static final Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    }
}
```

Now `Singleton.Holder` will only be initialized by using the `getInstance` method. It's lazy and thread-safe with no locking.

In my experience, usually a singleton class's *only* static method is the `getInstance` method, in which case they're equivalent (assuming you don't use reflection to initialize the type somehow, for example).

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you. But do we need other static methods in Singleton? So summary: without other static methods it's lazy, but with other static methods it's eager, right?

Comment: Yeah I think this is the most agreeable answer. Its a mighty difficult one though, what really throws off this question is that it is a singleton and thus has a reference to itself. That already makes it a bit vague what exactly the word "lazy" refers to here... lazy instantiation or lazy initialization? In the context of a singleton it is usually architecturally one and the same :/

Comment: @marshall: Well, with other static methods it's "eager when those other methods are called". Not the same as eager in terms of "when the app starts up" for example. Personally I'd try to avoid using a singleton anyway, in most cases :)

Comment: I avoid, it too: It does not look nice, if you have to add an static method resetSingleton() for unit tests, that uses reflection to reset the instance field

Answer (score 5):

It is not lazy because the singeton object is created once the class is loaded.
A lazy Singleton would create the object when it is first used.

Comment: But class will loaded only on getInstance() method, as I said in my Question. You didn't read or maybe disagree with me? Tell me why please, I can't understand.

Comment: The class could be loaded of you reference it. E.g Singleton theSingleton;

Comment: I disagree with you. Singleton theSingleton won't load the class.

Comment: @marshall: It may load the class but not initialize it. That may be VM-specific... not sure.

Comment: At least when you check the singleton later: if (theSingleton instanceof IFastSorter) { ...} else .., It is loaded.

Comment: @marshall Josh Blosh describes the Eagerly singleton in detail, have you read that? (Effective Java 2n Ed.) I have access to the book on some hours.

Comment: @AlexWien: No, an `instanceof` does *not* trigger a class loading. It would be stupid to load a class when you know in advance that an object can’t be an instance of a class which doesn’t have loaded yet. The JVM isn’t that stupid.

Comment: @AlexWien I tried instanceof right now, but it still didn't !INITIALIZE! class for me (don't know about loading, I'm talking about initializing static fields). Didn't read Effective Java, but I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view, the goal of being Lazy is to control when the instance of the Singleton is created. 
In this example, there is no control because there is a class variable (static member that is initialized when the class is initialized and not when getInstance() method is called).

That way, there is no control of when the Singleton is created.

But, if you initialize the variable, inside getInstance, you are getting control of when you want the Singleton to be created.

As you said, there are many examples of Singletons. I always try to go for Enums if I need them. 
You can find examples here: https://connected2know.com/programming/java-singleton-pattern/